# docker-compose.yml for Bitnami Apache, MariaDB, PrestaShop and PHPMyAdmin is not working correctly

Tags: docker-compose, bitnami, prestashop-1.7

My **1st goal** is to write a docker-compose.yml file with the following:

- 1 docker for the MariaDB server
- 1 docker for the PrestaShop-1.7 server
- 1 docker for the PHPMyAdmin server

Can you please help me get it working correctly ?

Then, **my 2nd goal** is to set passwords and disallow the "no password".

Kind regards, 
Arnaud.

I'm using the bitnami's dockers so I've started the following script:

```
version: "3"

networks:
  prestashop-network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  mariadb:
    image: 'bitnami/mariadb:10.3'
    environment:
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_prestashop
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_prestashop
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    networks: 
      - prestashop-network
    volumes:
      - 'mariadb_data:/bitnami'
    ports:
      - 3307:3306

  phpmyadmin:
    image: bitnami/phpmyadmin:latest
    volumes:
      - 'phpmyadmin_data:/bitnami'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    ports: 
      - 81:80 
    environment:
      - PHPMYADMIN_ALLOW_NO_PASSWORD=true
    networks: 
      - prestashop-network

  prestashop_1.7:
    image: 'bitnami/prestashop:1.7'
    volumes:
      - 'prestashop_data:/bitnami'
      - ./docker/prestashop/custom-php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
      - ./docker/prestashop/phpinfo.php:/var/www/html/phpinfo.php
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    ports:
      - 8085:80
      - 8086:443
    environment:
      - PRESTASHOP_FIRST_NAME=Toto
      - PRESTASHOP_LAST_NAME=FAMILLE
      - PRESTASHOP_PASSWORD=bitnami1
      - PRESTASHOP_EMAIL=user@example.com
      - PRESTASHOP_HOST=localhost
      - PRESTASHOP_COUNTRY=fr
      - PRESTASHOP_LANGUAGE=fr
      - MARIADB_HOST=mariadb
      - MARIADB_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - PRESTASHOP_DATABASE_USER=bn_prestashop
      - PRESTASHOP_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_prestashop
      - PRESTASHOP_DATABASE_PASSWORD=bitnami1
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MARIADB_ROOT_USER=root
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_CLIENT_CREATE_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_prestashop
      - MYSQL_CLIENT_CREATE_DATABASE_USER=bn_prestashop
      - SMTP_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
      - SMTP_PORT=587
      - SMTP_PROTOCOL=tls
      - SMTP_USER=your_email@gmail.com
      - SMTP_PASSWORD=your_password
    networks: 
      - prestashop-network  

volumes:
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local
  prestashop_data:
    driver: local
  phpmyadmin_data:
    driver: local
```

For information, I use Mac OS X Mojave with the following docker tools version:

```sh
$ docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b
docker-py version: 3.7.3
CPython version: 3.6.8
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0j  20 Nov 2018
```

When I launch with the following command:

```
docker-compose up
```

Then the different images are downloaded and started.

When I try to access the PhpMyAdmin instance using http://localhost:81 I can reach the PhpMyAdmin instance correctly using root and no password.

I get two major problems:

- I see the 'prestashop' database is **created but empty**
- When I try to access the PrestaShop instance using http://localhost:8085 I get an error 500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When tying your docker-compose file I got this errors:

```
mariadb_1         | 2019-08-15  9:28:47 13 [Warning] Access denied for user 'bn_prestashop'@'192.168.48.4' (using password: YES)
prestashop_1.7_1  | mysql-c ERROR [canConnect] Connection with 'bn_prestashop' user is unsuccessful
```

You need to set up the user password in the mariadb container too.

This docker-compose file worked for me, may be you can build up from here.

```
version: '2'

services:
  mariadb:
    image: 'bitnami/mariadb:10.1'
    environment:
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_prestashop
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_prestashop
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=my_passwd
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    volumes:
      - 'mariadb_data:/bitnami'
  prestashop:
    image: 'bitnami/prestashop:1.7'
    environment:
      - MARIADB_HOST=mariadb
      - MARIADB_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - PRESTASHOP_DATABASE_USER=bn_prestashop
      - PRESTASHOP_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_prestashop
      - PRESTASHOP_DATABASE_PASSWORD=my_passwd
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - PRESTASHOP_FIRST_NAME=Toto
      - PRESTASHOP_LAST_NAME=FAMILLE
      - PRESTASHOP_PASSWORD=bitnami1
      - PRESTASHOP_EMAIL=user@example.com
      - PRESTASHOP_HOST=localhost
      - PRESTASHOP_COUNTRY=fr
      - PRESTASHOP_LANGUAGE=fr
      - SMTP_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
      - SMTP_PORT=587
      - SMTP_PROTOCOL=tls
      - SMTP_USER=your_email@gmail.com
      - SMTP_PASSWORD=your_password
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - 'prestashop_data:/bitnami'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
  phpmyadmin:
    image: 'bitnami/phpmyadmin:4'
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
      - '8443:443'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    volumes:
      - 'phpmyadmin_data:/bitnami'
volumes:
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local
  prestashop_data:
    driver: local
  phpmyadmin_data:
    driver: local
```

Comment: Hi Raphael, Thank you very much! It's working on another Mac (I'm currently out of office). On my Mac desktop, what are the command I can use in order to clean my docker-compose installation? A *docker container rm IDs of old containers* followed by a *docker image rm IDs of old images* is it enough ?

Comment: With this command: $ docker-compose down -v --rmi all --remove-orphans